# device from NSEvent

Tags: objective-c, nsevent

I have an application that uses a barcode scanner. I want to be able to determine who pressed a key: the keyboard or the barcode scanner. I tried all the methods from the NSEvent, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant get device information using NSEvent.You shoud take a look at [DDHidLib](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/03/19/ddhidlib_10/). It will help you to work with usb devices.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at DDHidLib. I obtained a list of keyboards, but I do not know how to look for the event "keydown" for each keyboard. I tried startListening, but I don't understand how it works. Can you explain a little bit, because I couldn't find any documentation? Thanks